# Passing query results from Parse to NSArray iOS

Tags: ios, nsarray, parse-platform

I'm running a query with no problem, here is my code:

```
PFQuery *postQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"class"];
[postQuery whereKey:@"hasRelationship" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
// Run the query
[postQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        //Save results and update the table
        group = [objects valueForKey:@"groupArray"];
     }
}
```

The results are good, group console print is as follows:

```
(
("Register one",
"Register two",
"Register three",
"Register four")
)
```

BUT I need to have an array of length 4 not 1. Every time I strip the results by passing them into an NSString "mutable copy" like so crashes:

```
( NSString *s = (NSString *)[group objectAtIndex:0];
NSString * text = (NSString *)[s mutableCopy];)
```

Here is the error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:]: unrecognized selector sent ***
```

How can I get the elements inside the objects into an `NSArray` of length 4? Thanks!

Comment: Casting is not magic, it will just fool the compiler into thinking that your object is a string whereas it really is an array.

Comment: Check how you create the object that is printed into the console. You have an NSArray that contains another NSArray. Your first array has count=1 because is containing another NSArray. Your second array is the needed one and it has the count = 4. ;)

Comment: I finally got it, but thanks for the comments. Here is the solution:              //Save results into array:
             group = [[objects valueForKey:@"groupArray"] objectAtIndex:0];

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer to this one. Your query returned a result array with four objects in it. Casting doesn't change a fundamental object's type, it just tricks the compiler into thinking its dealing with a particular object's class. It doesn't actually change that class.

In this particular instance, its simple. There's already an array at index 0 in the current response:

NSArray *allGroups = group[0];

That should have all four strings in a single array which can be enumerated to do whatever you feel like doing.

Comment: Can't do it this way: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[PFObject countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]: unrecognized selector, I found the answer and posted it above, thanks!

Comment: The answer you posted in a comment is actually identical. Accessing an array with: -[anArray objectAtIndex: 0] is syntactically identical to accessing it using anArray[0];

Answer (score 0):

Look at their sample code to see how to use the array `objects`. So change your `if statement` use this:

```
if (!error) {
    // The find succeeded.
    NSLog(@"Successfully retrieved %d scores.", objects.count);
    // Do something with the found objects
    for (PFObject *object in objects) {
        NSLog(@"%@", object.objectId);
        // add to your array here
    }
  } else {
    // Log details of the failure
    NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
  }
}
```

or something simple as this:

```
if (!error) {
    // copy the array
    [group addObjectsFromArray:objects];
}
```